# Subversion Edge Support for ssh clarification

Tags: svn, ssh, active-directory

Can someone help me clarify this statement for subversion edge FAQ:

**"No support for svnserve or SSH"**

We're currently using the regular subversion/apache and we access the subversion using tortoisesvn client.  If I'm not mistaken, base on my research, the only way I can still use the ssh/tortoisesvn client is to also install svnserve (of course, assuming that there's no port conflict).

I'm exploring the possibility of migrating to subversion edge due to its simpler webgui to configure plus I'm also thinking of starting to use the active directory for authentication rather than the usual apache/svn authentication.  However my reservation is with the statement I pasted above.  Is that mean that I can no longer use tortoisesvn client to view and commit the work?

I hope I have provide enough information on what I need to find out.

Can someone please help me out with advise and clarification?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"No support for svnserve or SSH" means exactly written - Edge as server-side product can't create|handle `svn://` and `svn+ssh://` accessible repositories, only `http://`|`https://`

This fact doesn't correlate in any way with TortoiseSVN (or any other **SVN-client**), which, if otherwise not stated, support all possible access-protocols for repositories, served by **SVN-servers**

Comment: Thanks @lazy Badger.  Very helpful information..  I'll consider this question answered.